# The command-line doesn't execute

Tags: osx, block-device

I know that command is from Macbook Pro's terminal, but the command-line is the same as the one on Ubuntu. I'm trying to execute the following command-line, but I got an error :

[image]

Could anyone be able to tell me what's happening here?

Comment: unmount the disk before dd

Comment: [Please do not post screenshots of text. Copy-paste the text.](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to write to the block device `/dev/rdisk2`, which is 'busy'.  I'd guess this is possibly a removable disk, so a USB memory stick or a CD Drive.

If the Memory stick, is it currently mounted?  If so, you should try un-mounting it before writing to the block level of the device.  If it's a CD Drive, then it's probably not going to let you write to it like that.

Regardless of these, I am not sure a DMG file will create a viable file system if you do manage to block copy it onto the target device, I could be wrong I have never tried.  You can use Disk Util under MacOS to perform image writing type operations, which may be simpler overall than using `dd`.